# File Template extension with IntelliJ plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

So I want to create a file template in my IntelliJ IDEA plugin and I managed to mine these out from some other plugins, but the template always wants to be a java file and I cannot change the extension of it to be .cqt insteaf of .java
What I figured out:

I need to add these to the plugin.xml

```xml
<internalFileTemplate name="Croquette File" />
```

and I need

```xml
<createFromTemplateHandler implementation="...CroquetteCreateFromTemplateHandler" />
```

with the file creation action

```xml
<action
       id="Croquette.NewFile"
       class="...NewCroquetteFileDefinitionAction"
       text="Croquette File"
       description="Create a new Croquette file" >
    <add-to-group group-id="NewGroup" anchor="after" relative-to-action="NewGroup1"/>
</action>
```

The NewCroquetteFileDefinitionAction contains this:

```
class NewCroquetteFileDefinitionAction
        extends CreateFileFromTemplateAction(
            NewCroquetteFileDefinitionAction.NEW_CQT_FILE,
            "",
            CroquetteIcons.fileIcon)
        with DumbAware {

    import NewCroquetteFileDefinitionAction._

    override def buildDialog(
            project: Project,
            directory: PsiDirectory,
            builder: CreateFileFromTemplateDialog.Builder): Unit = {
        builder
            .setTitle(NEW_CQT_FILE)
            .addKind("Croquette File", CroquetteIcons.fileIcon, "Croquette File")
            .setValidator(new InputValidatorEx {
                override def getErrorText(inputString: String): String =
                    if (!inputString.isEmpty && !containsFuckyCharacters(inputString))
                        s"'$inputString' is not a valid Croquette file name."
                    else null

                override def checkInput(inputString: String): Boolean = getErrorText(inputString) != null


                override def canClose(inputString: String): Boolean = checkInput(inputString)
            })
    }

    override def getActionName(directory: PsiDirectory, newName: String, templateName: String): String = NEW_CQT_FILE

    override def hashCode(): Int = 0

    override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = obj.isInstanceOf[NewCroquetteFileDefinitionAction]
}

object NewCroquetteFileDefinitionAction {
    val NEW_CQT_FILE = "New Croquette File"

    def containsFuckyCharacters(strIn: String): Boolean = {
        List("+", "-", "<", ">", "\\", "/", ",", ".", "[", "]", "{", "}", "@", "&", "$", ";", "*").foreach(ch =>
            if (strIn.contains(ch))
                return true
        )
        false
    }
}
```

And I am guessing I have to do something here in the CroquetteDefaultPropertiesProvider class but not sure what, or even if that guess is correct or not as I cannot find any documentation on how to create file templates with plugins.

```
class CroquetteDefaultPropertiesProvider extends TemplatePackagePropertyProvider {

    override def fillProperties(directory: PsiDirectory, props: Properties) {
        super.fillProperties(directory, props)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put some `Name.your-lang-extension.ft` files under `fileTemplates` package, like [this](https://github.com/ice1000/julia-intellij/tree/master/res/fileTemplates), and declare `<internalFileTemplate name="Name" />`, like [this](https://github.com/ice1000/julia-intellij/blob/6fcf0de9a930d08bd091828c45ad51a590ced955/res/META-INF/plugin.xml#L10-L13) (this `Name` corresponds to the `Name` in `Name.your-lang-extension.ft`).
In the template files you may use some variables, there're some predefined ones and you can use your own. The syntax is `${MY_VAR}`.
Then you should implement `buildDialog` like [this](https://github.com/ice1000/julia-intellij/blob/6fcf0de9a930d08bd091828c45ad51a590ced955/src/org/ice1000/julia/lang/action/julia-file-actions.kt#L51), the third argument to `addKind` is the `Name` in `Name.your-lang-extension.ft`, the first one is the displayed name.

Then you should create a action class extending `CreateFileFromTemplateAction`, like [this](https://github.com/ice1000/julia-intellij/blob/master/src/org/ice1000/julia/lang/action/julia-file-actions.kt), and create a `Properties` instance by using `FileTemplateManager.getInstance(project).defaultProperties` like [this](https://github.com/ice1000/julia-intellij/blob/6fcf0de9a930d08bd091828c45ad51a590ced955/src/org/ice1000/julia/lang/action/julia-file-actions.kt#L37) and add some properties like [this](https://github.com/ice1000/julia-intellij/blob/6fcf0de9a930d08bd091828c45ad51a590ced955/src/org/ice1000/julia/lang/action/julia-file-actions.kt#L38-L39) which will be filled in to the variables, like you can `properties.add("MY_VAR", yourCodeToGetSomeInformation())` and `${MY_VAR}` in your template will the replaced with the return value of `yourCodeToGetSomeInformation()`.

After that you should implement `createFileFromTemplate` like [this](https://github.com/ice1000/julia-intellij/blob/6fcf0de9a930d08bd091828c45ad51a590ced955/src/org/ice1000/julia/lang/action/julia-file-actions.kt#L57), the key part is the call to `CreateFromTemplateDialog`'s `create()`, just look at my code example and you'll know.

After implementing the action class you should register it into `plugin.xml` just like what you're doing now.

BTW please remove your dangerously incorrect implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`.

You don't need a `createFromTemplateHandler`.