# How to add file templates to intellij plugin?

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

How can i add (already created) file templates to a custom **plugin** for intellij idea?

The official docs are empty for file templates, only live templates are described.

https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/live_templates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone needs the solution too...

1. Move your file templates to the resources subfolder, e.g. resources/fileTemplates
2. Add a .ft extension to your template files, e.g. TestTemplate.py.ft

A good example can be found here:
[File templates of the Julia plugin for the IntelliJ Platform](https://github.com/ice1000/julia-intellij/tree/master/res/fileTemplates)

See also:
[File Template extension with IntelliJ plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739361/file-template-extension-with-intellij-plugin)

Comment: How can this be done with a Framework during addSupport()?